# can I stop the play back using my app

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am using AudioPlayer to stop all playbacks , as code is given

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

But i can stop all play back using this but can not again play stopped play backs.How can I do this please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily play pause stop your AVAudioPlayer with these three methods:

```
- (void)pause
- (void)stop
- (BOOL)play //Returns YES on success, or NO on error.
```

If you pause, you can then play to resume from where you paused.

Hope this helps, i really don't see where your problem is!

---

in the code you gave, you are not pausing, you are just playing it with `numberOfLoops` negative.
You should have a method to start your music like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;//play once

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];        
[audioPlayer play];
```

And another for pausing:

```
[audioPlayer pause];
```

And another for resuming:

```
[audioPlayer play];
```

---

To toggle iPod music when the app starts and exits override these two methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    MPMusicPlayerController     *musicPlayer;   
    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [musicPlayer playbackState];
    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) { //simple verification
        [musicPlayer pause];
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {//simple verification
        [musicPlayer play];
}
    }
```

Hope it finally suits your needs!

Comment: see , i am listening music , i run my applications it should stop all play back , but play back start automatically when i tap on screen ,

Comment: Do you wnat to pause all playback which you started? or you mean iPod.app music?

Comment: yes , i can pause all playbacks using above trick but cant resume it

Comment: its not answer of my question

Comment: whats your question, i mean you want to pause some music that YOU play using AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: i want to pause playback volume , and it should resume when i stop this app[

Comment: oh you want to pause ipod music?